# What are the values of $z$ and $y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So we all know that $(x + a)(x + b) = x^2 + x(a + b) + ab$

Now I’m stuck to turn this:
$x^2 - 30x - 56$ into something like $(x+z)(x+y)$.

Here’s what I’ve done:
We know $y+z= -30$ and $yz = -56$ and let’s suppose $y > z$ so we know that $z$ is a negative number whereas $y$ is a positive number.

This is all I can figure out.
Any help?

Comment: It’s not possible to find rational $y$ and $z$.  If it was $+56$ instead of $-56$ one would have $z=2$ and $y=28$.

Comment: Are you sure you have it written correctly?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe but 2 + 28 is 30 not -30

Comment: @Clayton the maybe things that I “figured out” are wrong but x^2 - 30x - 56 is right

Comment: Take $z=-28$ and $y=-2$.

Comment: As for factoring the expression, the "quadratic formula" should do the trick just fine.  If you don't know what i'm talking about just from that phrase, googlesearch it.

Comment: Notice that $-z$ and $-y$ are the zeros of that quadratic polynomial. So just solve $x^2 - 30x -56=0$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard root-finding formula yields

$$-a,-b=30\pm\sqrt{30^2+56}$$ which aren't integers.